# How to migrate an Openerp v7 database to Odoo v8?

Tags: odoo, database-migration, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have a dump file of database backup(openerp-7). Now I want to continue my work in Odoo, the database is in openerp-7 format so I am not able to restore it in Odoo. How to convert this database to Odoo version in order to start working on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do a data migration. That's not an easy task. You can use some of this migration tools:

- [OpenUpgrade](https://doc.therp.nl/openupgrade/).
- Or you can use some ETL tool such as [Odoo ETL](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/etl/)
- If you only want migrate some table you can export it in a CSV file and import it in Odoo choosing the right columns.

Comment: How to use that ETL tool, I have openerp 7 database which i want to convert to version 8.When i enter my source database name it says no such database exists.

Comment: Search in Youtube "Odoo ETL". I'm sure you can find some tutorials like that

Answer (score 0):

Using pgadmin3,we can export the tables and import in our desired database of version 8