# How to clone database schema and data to Odoo 10 or 11 from Odoo 8 (no modules, only database)?

Tags: postgresql, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

Can I clone database from previous version of Odoo (I have Odoo 8)? If "yes", by what method?

I tried exporting and re-importing data but I have an error.

Comment: share your try code and exception

Comment: So you want to migrate one database from Odoo 8 to Odoo 10? Maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32713292/4891717) can help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate odoo 8 to odoo 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151342/how-to-migrate-odoo-8-to-odoo-10)

Comment: in these questions they talk of module, my problem is data, 
as soon as possibile i upload the error that odoo take me

Answer (score 0):

You can take the database using `pg_dump dbname > db_filename.sql` although you cannot use the same database in other odoo versions since there is a lot of schematic changes in your database that is different in different versions of odoo.
In order to do so you need to migrate the database from one version to another. 
There is [OpenUpgrade](https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade) that allows migration from odoo 8 to 9.